# Random error Memory stream is not expandable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wordprocessingml

I was updating word document content using following code which was randomly throwing error Memory stream is not expandable:

```
MemoryStream TemplateFileMS = new MemoryStream(fileBytes);
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(TemplateFileMS, true))
//...
// some code
//...
wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save(); // Exception here
```

After changing the code to below, the error is not occurring.

```
MemoryStream TemplateFileMS = new MemoryStream(0);
TemplateFileMS.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
```

So I am able to fix the issue. But I didn't see the above error in my dev environment on Azure App Service but in the production Azure App Service I was getting the Memory is not expandable error randomly.

Is it related to the number of bytes/updates that is making difference here? e.g. while testing I make only few updates but in some scenarios there are more updates which requires extra memory than the set capacity.

I tried adding more updates to the document but I was not able to reproduce this error with previous code.

Thank you!

Comment: We don't know how large `fileBytes` is - and in particular, in the first snippet we have no idea how `wordDoc` is related to `TemplateFileMS`. Please provide a [mcve] - the lack of information makes it much harder for us to help you.

Comment: Instead of passing `0` as the capacity pass the expected buffer size. Even a rough estimate will eliminate a *lot* of the buffer reallocations needed as `MemoryStream` expands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you'd only initialize a MemoryStream from a byte[] to *read* values from an existing buffer. But you are *writing* to the stream. That means you either need to let the MemoryStream manage the buffers itself (by not giving it one), or the buffer you give it **needs to be big enough**. In most cases the first option is simpler. It is complaining because you have given it a buffer that turned out to be too small, but it can't resize it because *you defined the buffer externally* (rather than letting the MemoryStream have control).

Comment: Thank you Marc! So its probably because the provided buffer is smaller than what is required in few cases where I get error. Otherwise if the updates are small to accommodate in the provided buffer it works without the error. Am I right in understanding?

Comment: @SushrutParanjape exactly that, yes

Comment: Thank you Marc for the help!